# Highlight parts of search results

Tags: php

I'm using the code below for highlight one word from file_get_content and go to anchor.

```
$file='
IAR6=1002
SHF6=1
REF6=0002
TY7=2
DATE7=20130820182357
STAT_N7=1002
SEQ7=0002110000001
STA7=000005
TY8=2
DATE8=20130820182429
STAT_N8=1002
SH8=1
OP8=S123
SEQ8=0002120000081
';

$Seq = 0002110000001;
$text = preg_replace("/\b($Seq)\b/i", '<span class="highlight"><a name="here">\1</a></span>', $file);
```

for now this highlight : 0002110000001

i would like to highlight all part of the same index number.

ex:
looking for 0002110000001

highlight this part of txt only where number is 7

```
TY7=2
DATE7=20130820182357
STAT_N7=1002
SEQ7=0002110000001
STA7=000005
```

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
i try to be more specific.
file contain lot of code parts always start by TYx (x is auto numbering)

i have the SEQ number for my search , in ex 0002110000001
the preg_replace("/\b($Seq)\b/i", '\1 find 0002110000001 and higlight them.

what i need is higlight what is between TY7 and TY8 instead of only 0002110000001.

Hope this is clear enough due to my bad english

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **`stripos()`** and **`explode()`** in PHP

```
<?php
$file='
IAR6=1002
SHF6=1
REF6=0002
TY7=2
DATE7=20130820182357
STAT_N7=1002
SEQ7=0002110000001
STA7=000005
TY8=2
DATE8=20130820182429
STAT_N8=1002
SH8=1
OP8=S123
SEQ8=0002120000081
';
//$Seq = "0002110000001";
$Seq = "7";
$new_arr=explode(PHP_EOL,$file);
foreach($new_arr as $k=>$v)
{
if(stripos($v,$Seq)!==false)
{
echo "$v\n";
}
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
TY7=2
DATE7=20130820182357
STAT_N7=1002
SEQ7=0002110000001
STA7=000005
```

Comment: thanks to answer , but this extract part of and not higlight, and if i have typ71 this does not work. the goal is to higlight and go to anchor portion not truncate (file can contain more than 1500 id)

Comment: What should `typ71` match with ?

Comment: Sorry this is not TYP but TY ! .I probably misspoke , file exemple is only a small portion of file. it contain more than 1500 parts of codes starting with TYx (x=auto numbering) so TY1,TY2 ... i'm start editing my post to be more specific.